# What does "implements" mean in Python class definition?

Tags: python, import, python-import, beeware, voc

The bellow code sample is from a BeeWare suite example. (https://github.com/eliasdorneles/drawingapp-voc/blob/master/drawingapp/app.py)

What does the expression `implements=android.view.View[OnClickListener]` means? There should be (a list of) base class(es). Is it some incompatible special syntax of the framework or standard python I can not comprehend (and missing from the documentation)?

Moreover, we are using `OnClickListener` here which is never imported. There is no wildcard imports (*) and no module prefix before the symbol like `android.Constants.OnClickListener` or someting like that. How can the Python interpreter find the `OnClickListener` value in this case?

```
import android
from android.widget import LinearLayout, TextView, Button
import android.content.Context
from android.graphics import Bitmap, Canvas, Color, Paint, Path, PorterDuff
from android.view import MotionEvent, Gravity
import android.view

class ButtonClick(implements=android.view.View[OnClickListener]):
    def __init__(self, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callback = callback
```

'''

Comment: In the readme it says that this python code is compiled to Java. So I belive that code is never supposed to be run on a standard interpreter and in fact raises an exception.

Comment: Python's [class definition syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) lets you use `keyword=value` entries just as much as base classes. By default `metaclass=...` has meaning, and when using [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), other such keyword arguments are passed on to that method. Presumably the BeeWare suite is relying on that syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the key to the mistery here is that this is not quite Python code-  rather, it is a source file meant to be transpiled with [VOC](https://pybee.org/project/projects/bridges/voc/) - that will generate Java bytecode, which will be further processed to work as an Android application using the standard Android Api.

As a transpiler, VOC relies on syntax which are valid Python, but it  allows itself to take detours from the official language - like using keyword arguments on class definitions. That would only make sense in Python if it were inheriting a class which would implement the special method `__init_subclass__`, or use a custom metaclass to interpret these arguments - otherwise they'd have no effect. Also, VOC probably use these keywords (`extends` and `implements`) to indicate exactly these words as they are in Java class declaration syntax.

Also, as you put it, the name `OnClickListener` as it is in there would fail with a `NameError` in normal Python - it is likely that VOC defines additional names that behave like builtin names. In ordinary Python, if you create a function/method definition instead of a class definition, it is possible to makeuse of non-imported or undefined names as annotations. That is  `android.view.View[OnClickListener]` would follow `:` instead of `=`, in a function definition. Annotations are lazily evaluated in Python 3.7 (but not in Python 3.6), so it would not cause an error. As it is, though, it would just raise a NameError in normal Python.

Here is a quick start for Python android apps using VOC in PyBee https://pybee.org/project/using/android-app/

**update** answer extensively reworded after I found out about VOC, though the first findings on "this is not Python" were correct)

Answer (score 2):

Python's [class definition syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) lets you use `keyword=value` entries just as much as base classes. By default `metaclass=...` has meaning, and when using [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), other such keyword arguments are passed on to that method.  So using `implements=` in a class definition is fine from a syntax point of view.

Note that BeeWare *doesn't run Python* on Android, it uses a [transpiler called VoC](https://pybee.org/project/projects/bridges/voc/) to translate Python code to Java. The `implements=` keyword argument in classes is used to [let you define Java interfaces in Python code](https://voc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-1.html#implementing-a-java-interface). Presumably the additional names like `OnClickListener` are available because VoC makes them available.

VoC translates Python bytecode to Java, so all that BeeWare compatible Python has to achieve is to be *correct Python syntax*. Runtime issues such as `NameError`s don't have to be a problem, that's something the Java translator can compensate for.